# Internet Explorer Compatibility Value Error

Tags: internet-explorer, compatibility, valueerror

I am not sure here is the right place to ask this kind of questions but I encountered with a different kind of issue I could not resolved. One of website shows all values like multiplied 100, when I removed to compatibility view of internet explorer it turns to zero value, but when I add it again it does not show correct value.

[This view is with compatibility view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C5KD0.png)

Below values show total of above values, it should be 619,536.76 not 61,953,676.00 Also above values should be shifted two digit to right.

[This view is without compatibility view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cl2iE.png)

As you can see on this image above values are correct but sum turns out to zero.

I tried to change Regional view settings, it is in English(US) with all formats like number and currency, I could not find a solution to fix this problem also I could not find where this problem comes from? Is there an option to reset compatibility settings?

Thank you in advance

Comment: I am sorry to hear that you still have to deal with IE.

Comment: Unfortunately website was written for IE and could not work with any other browser

Comment: Whether you are using some JQuery calculate plugin? Try to use [F12 Developer Tools](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/samples/dn255006(v%3dvs.85)) to check whether it contains some error when you change the Internet Explorer Compatibility Value.